# How do I animate two letters swapping?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, css-animations

I am trying to make a website where hovering over a misspelling consisting of transposition of two letters corrects it, like so:

```js
var swap = document.querySelector('.swap');

swap.addEventListener('mouseover', swapIn);
swap.addEventListener('mouseout', swapOut);

function swapIn(e) {
  e.target.parentNode.firstChild.classList.toggle('shifted-right');
  e.target.parentNode.lastChild.classList.toggle('shifted-left');
}

function swapOut(e) {
  e.target.parentNode.firstChild.classList.toggle('shifted-right');
  e.target.parentNode.lastChild.classList.toggle('shifted-left');
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.swap {
  display: inline;
}

span {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.shifted-right {
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: blue;
}

.shifted-left {
  margin-left: -25px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
E<div class="swap" id="swap"><span class="left-swap" id="ls">q</span><span class="right-swap" id="rs">c</span></div>uis me vivit fortunatior?
```

However, as you can see, the letters don't swap well, and besides, I don't want to calculate the precise margins for each different letter width.

What's a better approach to doing this?

Comment: Use animations / transitions with `transform` instead of `margin`.

Comment: Though, you will *have* to calculate the distances each letter has to travel because of the dynamic nature what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switching two letters in the same word can be done by calculating their relative position to their parent with the [`offsetLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft) property.

Subtract the values from each other and use [`Math.abs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) to keep the integer a positive number. This number is the `distance` between the two letters. One letter has to go the entire distance to the left and the other the same distance to the right to switch positions. Set the a CSS Variable with the distance so we can pass the calculation to CSS.

In CSS we can use the `:hover` pseudo selector to set styles on hover and use the CSS Variable to make the proper transition. And instead of targeting the hover on a letter, target the hover on the entire word.

Instead of `margin`, use [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transforms/Using_CSS_transforms); this property does not mess with the layout and will only any manipulate the element that is targeted.

```js
const word = document.querySelector('.word');
const [e, a] = word.querySelectorAll('.letter');
const distance = Math.abs(e.offsetLeft - a.offsetLeft);
word.style.setProperty('--distance', `${distance}px`);
```

```css
.word {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 32px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border: 1px dashed #d0d0d0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: help;
}

.word .letter {
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
  transition: color 500ms ease-in-out, transform 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.word:hover .letter {
  color: green;
}

.word:hover .letter:first-of-type {
  transform: translate(var(--distance), 0);
}

.word:hover .letter:last-of-type {
  transform: translate(calc(var(--distance) * -1), 0);
}
```

```html
<span class="word">
  App<span class="letter">e</span>r<span class="letter">a</span>nt
</span>
```